# Optimization of a logic at different levels of abstraction (group, time)

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

I'm trying to optimize a code that refers to different levels of abstraction of a data table without success for the moment.

I have a data table with different `id`. The logic of the code applies independently to each `id`.

I have for each `id` a reference date (`date_ref`) and a reference value (`value_ref`) then I have a `date` sequence with different `value` for the same `c(date_ref, value_ref)`.

An `id` has different `date_ref` and `value_ref` with each time a corresponding `date` sequence.

The data table looks like this:

```
   id value_ref   date_ref       date     value
 1:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-15  50.00000
 2:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-16  55.20833
 3:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-17  60.41667
 4:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-18  65.62500
 5:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-19  70.83333
 6:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-20  76.04167
 7:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-21  81.25000
 8:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-22  86.45833
 9:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-23  91.66667
10:  1       100 2019-12-25 2019-12-24  96.87500
11:  1        50 2020-01-01 2019-12-22  86.45833
12:  1        50 2020-01-01 2019-12-23  91.66667
```

The logic is the following. If some of the `date` are earlier than a `date_ref` then the `value_ref` of this `date_ref` should be subtracted from the `value` of all these `date` (and stores in `newvalue`).  It is possible that several `value_ref` should be subtracted from the `value` of the same date. If the substraction result is negative then the result is equal to zero.

To better understand the logic, please refer to the code and viz below.

I can implement it with loops, as shown below, but this code is obviously very slow and I have the intuition that it is possible to optimize it significantly but I haven't found the best approach angle yet.

I usually work with `data.table` but other solutions are also welcome.

### Sample data

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 30), rep(2, 20)),
  value_ref = rep(c(100, 50, 200, 150, 300), each = 10),
  date_ref = as.Date(rep(
    c("2019-12-25",
      "2020-01-01",
      "2020-01-05",
      "2020-01-30",
      "2020-02-01"),
    each = 10
  ))
)
dt[ , date := date_ref %m-% days(rep(10:1, 5))]

value <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2019-12-25') %m-% days(10),as.Date('2020-02-01'),by = 1),
           value = seq(50,300, 250/48))
dt <- merge(dt, value, by = "date", all.x = T)
dt[ , newvalue := value]
```

### Slow solution

```
for (ID in unique(dt$id)) {
  date_ref_ids <- unique(dt[id == ID,  date_ref])
  for (date_ref_id in date_ref_ids) {
    concurrent_ids <- unique(dt[id == ID &
                                  date_ref != date_ref_id &
                                  date_ref >= min(dt[date_ref == date_ref_id, date]) &
                                  date_ref <= max(dt[date_ref == date_ref_id, date]),
                                .(value_ref, date_ref)])
    for (concurrent_ids_date_ref in concurrent_ids$date_ref) {
      dt[id == id &
           date_ref == date_ref_id &
           date <= concurrent_ids_date_ref,
         newvalue := value - concurrent_ids[date_ref == concurrent_ids_date_ref, value_ref]]
    }
  }
}
```

### Plot

Here is a visualisation of the expected result:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

g1 <- dt %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=date, y=value, group=paste(id, date_ref), color=paste(id, date_ref))) +
  geom_line() +
  ylim(c(0,300)) +
  theme_classic()

g2 <- dt %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=date, y=newvalue, group=paste(id, date_ref), color=paste(id, date_ref))) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic() +
  ylim(c(0,300))

grid.arrange(g1, g2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't `newvalue` in first row be -300 (50 - 100 - 50 - 200)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you described is a bit different from that implied from your code, which suggests the following procedure:

1. for each `date`, `date_ref` and `value` combination, find all the other `date_ref`s prior to `date_ref` but greater than or equal to `date`;
2. let the temporary result be `value` minus all `value_ref`s found;
3. return the maximum between 0 and this temporary result.

Assume that the logic implied from your code is the desired one. We can use `data.table`'s non-equal join to achieve that. Consider something as follows

```
dt[, newvalue := value][
  unique(dt, by = c("id", "date_ref", "value_ref")), 
  newvalue := pmax(0L, newvalue - i.value_ref), 
  on = .(id = id, date_ref > date_ref, date <= date_ref), by = .EACHI
]
```

Note that `newvalue` will be updated repeatedly if there are multiple matches for `value_ref` on the conditions specified, as per your requirement.

Output

```
          date id value_ref   date_ref     value   newvalue
 1: 2019-12-15  1       100 2019-12-25  50.00000  50.000000
 2: 2019-12-16  1       100 2019-12-25  55.20833  55.208333
 3: 2019-12-17  1       100 2019-12-25  60.41667  60.416667
 4: 2019-12-18  1       100 2019-12-25  65.62500  65.625000
 5: 2019-12-19  1       100 2019-12-25  70.83333  70.833333
 6: 2019-12-20  1       100 2019-12-25  76.04167  76.041667
 7: 2019-12-21  1       100 2019-12-25  81.25000  81.250000
 8: 2019-12-22  1       100 2019-12-25  86.45833  86.458333
 9: 2019-12-22  1        50 2020-01-01  86.45833   0.000000
10: 2019-12-23  1       100 2019-12-25  91.66667  91.666667
11: 2019-12-23  1        50 2020-01-01  91.66667   0.000000
12: 2019-12-24  1       100 2019-12-25  96.87500  96.875000
13: 2019-12-24  1        50 2020-01-01  96.87500   0.000000
14: 2019-12-25  1        50 2020-01-01 102.08333   2.083333
15: 2019-12-26  1        50 2020-01-01 107.29167 107.291667
16: 2019-12-26  1       200 2020-01-05 107.29167  57.291667
17: 2019-12-27  1        50 2020-01-01 112.50000 112.500000
18: 2019-12-27  1       200 2020-01-05 112.50000  62.500000
19: 2019-12-28  1        50 2020-01-01 117.70833 117.708333
20: 2019-12-28  1       200 2020-01-05 117.70833  67.708333
21: 2019-12-29  1        50 2020-01-01 122.91667 122.916667
22: 2019-12-29  1       200 2020-01-05 122.91667  72.916667
23: 2019-12-30  1        50 2020-01-01 128.12500 128.125000
24: 2019-12-30  1       200 2020-01-05 128.12500  78.125000
25: 2019-12-31  1        50 2020-01-01 133.33333 133.333333
26: 2019-12-31  1       200 2020-01-05 133.33333  83.333333
27: 2020-01-01  1       200 2020-01-05 138.54167  88.541667
28: 2020-01-02  1       200 2020-01-05 143.75000 143.750000
29: 2020-01-03  1       200 2020-01-05 148.95833 148.958333
30: 2020-01-04  1       200 2020-01-05 154.16667 154.166667
31: 2020-01-20  2       150 2020-01-30 237.50000 237.500000
32: 2020-01-21  2       150 2020-01-30 242.70833 242.708333
33: 2020-01-22  2       150 2020-01-30 247.91667 247.916667
34: 2020-01-22  2       300 2020-02-01 247.91667  97.916667
35: 2020-01-23  2       150 2020-01-30 253.12500 253.125000
36: 2020-01-23  2       300 2020-02-01 253.12500 103.125000
37: 2020-01-24  2       150 2020-01-30 258.33333 258.333333
38: 2020-01-24  2       300 2020-02-01 258.33333 108.333333
39: 2020-01-25  2       150 2020-01-30 263.54167 263.541667
40: 2020-01-25  2       300 2020-02-01 263.54167 113.541667
41: 2020-01-26  2       150 2020-01-30 268.75000 268.750000
42: 2020-01-26  2       300 2020-02-01 268.75000 118.750000
43: 2020-01-27  2       150 2020-01-30 273.95833 273.958333
44: 2020-01-27  2       300 2020-02-01 273.95833 123.958333
45: 2020-01-28  2       150 2020-01-30 279.16667 279.166667
46: 2020-01-28  2       300 2020-02-01 279.16667 129.166667
47: 2020-01-29  2       150 2020-01-30 284.37500 284.375000
48: 2020-01-29  2       300 2020-02-01 284.37500 134.375000
49: 2020-01-30  2       300 2020-02-01 289.58333 139.583333
50: 2020-01-31  2       300 2020-02-01 294.79167 294.791667
```

Benchmark

```
f1 <- function(dt) {
  for (ID in unique(dt$id)) {
    date_ref_ids <- unique(dt[id == ID,  date_ref])
    for (date_ref_id in date_ref_ids) {
      concurrent_ids <- unique(dt[id == ID &
                                    date_ref != date_ref_id &
                                    date_ref >= min(dt[date_ref == date_ref_id, date]) &
                                    date_ref <= max(dt[date_ref == date_ref_id, date]),
                                  .(value_ref, date_ref)])
      for (concurrent_ids_date_ref in concurrent_ids$date_ref) {
        dt[id == id &
             date_ref == date_ref_id &
             date <= concurrent_ids_date_ref,
           newvalue := value - concurrent_ids[date_ref == concurrent_ids_date_ref, value_ref]]
      }
    }
  }
}


f2 <- function(dt) {
  dt[, newvalue := value][
    unique(dt, by = c("id", "date_ref", "value_ref")), 
    newvalue := newvalue - i.value_ref, 
    on = .(id = id, date_ref > date_ref, date <= date_ref), by = .EACHI
  ]
}

dt1 = copy(dt); dt2 = copy(dt)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(dt1), f2(dt2))
```

Result

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq     max neval cld
 f1(dt1) 22.988901 24.67485 26.495538 25.869601 27.403650 38.0660   100   b
 f2(dt2)  3.212501  3.40915  3.829885  3.551501  3.959951 13.0712   100  a
```